# how to implement this logic with node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js, I want to replace a application I made in C# with node.js  but the async nature of node is throwing me off:

I would like to do this:

```
1- Read N files, parse them and fill an array with the values from the files. 
2- Then every 30 seconds I need to read the files again and get the latest values in the file, added them to the array.
3- but immediately after step 1 is complete I can start a web server that will receive request from a browser. the server needs to send to the client some values form the array.
```

So I need the continuous loop for the web server (after the initial values are loaded) to be able to replies to the clients and at the same time I need to refresh the array periodically

With the existing app I do this:

```
1- read files , fill array
2- start a thread to server the clients (until app is closed)
3- start a thread to read the files again every N seconds and add new values to array  (until app is closed)
```

I would greatly appreciate any ideas to go about this, thank you

Comment: You might want to look at http://expressjs.com/ .

Comment: Asking for help correcting attempted code is good here, but asking for complete implementations isn't.  Try something, post that in your question and people will bite :)

Comment: thank you alain but I am not asking for a complete implementation, just some  pointers to get me started if this is possible

Answer (score -1):

I would listen for events for these files using streams , it's better for performance and also can listen for events (like if it has data) if they have any data then I would read that and pipe that to other writable streams (like your http response ) , I prefer using stream and events instead of using timers, for example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

stream.on('data',function(d){
  //just pipe it to your writable stream (you can use the http response)
});
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: thank you Bassam, ...you mean, read the files syncronically first, fill the array , then set a stream for the current file and 
subscribe to the data event, when it gets written then copy that data to the array, that way the array 
is updated as the data comes in. 

then also create the "http-server-like" function? the idea is that by means 
of the data-event the array is 
populated and when a client request data node.js will execute that part ?

Comment: I meant to read files async with streams , because it's better  performance and it's event based "Emmiter" so you can check the stream if it contains data and you can pipe it to other writable streams (like the response)